# Reshaping, Flattening, or Raveling a Multidimensional Array within a Class

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, subclass

I am somewhat of a beginner when it comes to using Matplotlib and Python in general. I am trying to create a class that can generate multiple subplots given basic information such as how many rows and columns the user wants. I am running into an issue when trying to convert the multidimensional array that comes from `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()`. Here is a copy of what I am working with currently:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class subplotgrid:
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, width, height): # class initialization
      self.rows = rows
      self.cols = cols
      self.width = width
      self.height = height
      self.pltarray = [] # refers to the subplot number, values are 0 - (rows x cols)

    def create(self, h_spacing = 0.2, w_spacing =0.1): # generate the subplots,
                                                       # h_spcing and v_spacing are optional params with default values
      fig, pltarray = plt.subplots(self.rows, self.cols, figsize=(rows*self.width, cols*self.height))  # Creates subplots, rows x cols, total figure size
      fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .2, wspace=.1)     # Specifies spaces between each subplot
      self.pltarray = self.pltarray.reshape(-1)  # axes within plt.subplot() are multidimensional arrays that can't be iterated over, so we have to flatten it with .ravel()

    def show_scatter(self, x_array, y_array, dotSize = 0.5, title = "DEFAULT TITLE"):
      for i in range(0, rows+cols-1):    # loops through all of the subplots   
        self.pltarray[i].scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1], s=dotSize, c='red')            # Scatter plot all points red
        self.pltarray[i].scatter(inside[:,0],inside[:,1],s=dotSize, c='blue')  # Scatter plot points inside blue
        if (isinstance(title, np.ndarray)): # check if we are passing an array of titles, test passes True if we are
          pltarray[i].set_title(title[i]) # set the title to the indexed title for the title array
        else:
           axs[i].set_title(title) # set the title to a static value if no title array was found

      plt.show()
```

however the line `self.pltarray = self.reshape(-1)` throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'subplotgrid' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

with similar issues for `.ravel()` and `.flatten()` respectively. Why does this error show up and how does one go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

You are reshaping your own class `self.reahape(-1)` which has no reshape method implemented. You need to reshape the axis array:

```
self.pltarray = pltarray.reshape(-1)
```

Comment: I editted the post with the correction to `self.pltarray = self.pltarray.reshape(-1)`. I also tested your solution but the same error was generated

Comment: `pltarray.reshape(-1)` not `self.pltarray.reshape(-1)`

Comment: the same error occured when I ran that as well